# Why do we need to use an -ing verb/gerund after 'when'? What is 'when' actually?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-construction, conjunctions, parts-of-speech

I have a long-standing doubt on 'when'.

---

> 1) Is it a conjunction or preposition?

I don't know whether it is preposition or not, for every verb after it will take -ing or becomes a gerund:

> 1) Before/After/When study**ing**, don't talk to her.

---

If it is not a preposition, why does it behave so?

Comment: Because the simple rule, it can't have more than one verb in a sentence.

Comment: @Zhang There is no rule that limits a sentence using "when" to a single verb. For example: "When you drive, you fly". (This could have several meanings, but the most obvious is "when you drive an automobile, you go too fast." That also has two verbs after 'when' come to think of it.)

Answer (score 1):

At least according to Merriam-Webster, *when* can function in four different ways—and none of them is as a preposition.

Also, it doesn't require verbs following it to take an *-ing* form. The following version of the example sentence would also be fine:

> When you study, don't talk to her.

---

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/when):

> *adverb*
>   **1** :at what time
>   // *when* will you return
>
> *conjunction*
>   **1 a** :at or during the time that: WHILE
>   // went fishing *when* he was a boy
>   **1 b** : just at the moment that
>   // stop writing *when* the bell rings
>   **1 c** : at any or every time that
>   // *when* he listens to music, he falls asleep
>
> *pronoun*
>   : what or which time
>   // life-long homes for those … who have lived here since *when*
>   — Kim Waller
>
> *noun*
>   : the time in which something is done or comes
>   // about troubled his head very little about the hows and *whens* of life
>   — Laurence Sterne

---

In the case of the example sentence, it's being used as a conjunction. Although the first example sentence of Merriam-Webster's definition of its adverbial sense starts with *when*, it's not being used to join two clauses together.